# Webpack and Tree Shaking with Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, webpack-5

I created a `Vue 3.2.40` application using `Webpack 5.76.2` and `Webpack CLI 4.10.0`. I build a global component **my-component.js**:

```js
import SecondComponent from './second-component.vue';
app.component('global-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Hi!</h1>
      <second-component></second-component>
    </div>
  `,
 components: {
   SecondComponent
 }
})
```

The imported **second-component.vue**:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="red-class">{{ someData }}</div>
    <button class="red-class" @click="myFirstFunction">Click Me</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { myMixin } from "./mixin.js";

export default {
  name: "second-component",
  mixins: [myMixin],
  data: function () {
    return {
      someData: "Just some data!",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

The imported **myMixin.js**:

```js
export const myMixin = {
  methods: {
    myFirstFunction: function () {
      console.log("Foo");
    },
    mySecondFunction: function () {
      console.log("Bar");
    }
  }
};
```

Here are the webpack configuration **webpack.config.js**:

```js
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: {
    global_component: "./global-component.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}`,
    filename: "[name]_bundled.js",
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".vue"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: "vue-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "vue-style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "esbuild-loader",
            options: {
              loader: "css",
              minify: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    // Here you tell webpack to take Vue from CDN
    vue: "Vue",
  },
  plugins: [new VueLoaderPlugin()],
  optimization: {
    usedExports: true,
  },
};
```

As you can see in **myMixin.js** i have 2 functions and only one of them i'm using in **second-component.vue** and that is `myFirstFunction`. With Webpack and Tree Shaking i want to bundel only used functions that's mean the final bundel should have just one function `myFirstFunction`. But in my final bundel i have both functions. The second one i don't need `mySecondFunction`. That should do the tree shaking for me because second functions is dead-code and it should be eliminated.

I tried to use `"sideEffects": false` in **package.json** and also `usedExports: true` in **webpack.config.js** but that's not working.

For tests i made a new [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/webpack5-vue3-forked-qq9xhf?file=%2Fmixin.js%3A6%2C21). I will be happy if someone can help me to deal with that problem.